# Breakpoint at Javascript error in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, breakpoints, microsoft-edge

I want to tell Microsoft Edge to halt execution, preferably with a Javascript call stack and a debugger, whenever there is a javascript error. I case it's unclear what constitutes an "error", I mean the problem that caused the output shown below.

[image: javascripterror]

Can I do that? If so, how?

Comment: @Teemu A break-on-error feature is a common feature in a JavaScript debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the F12 developer tools go to the debugger tab, then select the hexagon icon with a Pause button on it (or press Ctrl + Shift + E) Then select "Break on all Expectations"